# responsive divider between two column using tailwind css

Tags: css, responsive-design, tailwind-css

With the inspiration from dribble design where two columns are separated by a line with or text in the middle, I tried to do the same but I could not show the or text in the middle with vertical line above and below of it if it's not a mobile device otherwise horizontal separator with same or text.

This is the design which I am trying to mimic
[image]

Here is my code along with tailwind playground

```
<div class="min-h-screen bg-gray-100 py-6 flex flex-col justify-center sm:py-12">
  <div class="relative px-4 py-10 bg-white shadow-lg sm:rounded-1xl sm:p-20">
    <div class="grid sm:grid-cols-3 gap-4">
      <div>
        <h1 class="font-bold text-blue-500 text-lg">I want to sell</h1>
        <p class="text-sm font-light text-gray-400 pt-4 pb-4">Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit...</p>
        <button class="bg-blue-500 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4">Sell</button>
      </div>
      <div class="or-divider">
        <p class="font-bold text-gray-500 rounded-full bg-gray-50 flex items-center justify-center text-sm" style="height: 50px; width: 50px;">or</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h1 class="font-bold text-blue-500 text-lg">I want to buy</h1>
        <p class="text-sm font-light text-gray-400 pt-4 pb-4">Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit...</p>
        <button class="bg-blue-500 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4">Buy</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

.or-divider:after, .or-divider:before {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: 2px;
  background-color: #9994;
  height: 100%;
}
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/detgHQImBz?file=css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your code, I did the following modifications

- change grid template from 3 columns to 2 for screen size bigger than small
- use `border-r` class to create the vertical line at the right of the first column when screen size bigger than small
- use `border-b` class to create the horizontal line at the bottom of the first element when screen size smaller than small
- `absolute` position the "or" object `relative` to the first element

Below a snippet with the code:

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="min-h-screen bg-gray-100 py-6 flex flex-col justify-center sm:py-12">
  <div class="relative px-4 py-10 bg-white shadow-lg sm:rounded-1xl sm:p-20">
    <div class="grid sm:grid-cols-2 gap-4">
      <div class="border-b sm:border-b-0 sm:border-r p-8 relative">
        <h1 class="font-bold text-blue-500 text-lg">I want to sell</h1>
        <p class="text-sm font-light text-gray-400 pt-4 pb-4">Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit...</p>
        <button class="bg-blue-500 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4">Sell</button>
        <div class="hidden sm:block absolute right-0 transform translate-x-7 top-1/2 -translate-y-7">
          <p class="font-bold text-gray-500 rounded-full bg-gray-50 flex items-center justify-center text-sm" style="height: 50px; width: 50px;">or</p>
        </div>
        <div class="sm:hidden absolute transform bottom-0 left-1/2 translate-y-6 -translate-x-7">
          <p class="font-bold text-gray-500 rounded-full bg-gray-50 flex items-center justify-center text-sm" style="height: 50px; width: 50px;">or</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="p-8">
        <h1 class="font-bold text-blue-500 text-lg">I want to buy</h1>
        <p class="text-sm font-light text-gray-400 pt-4 pb-4">Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit...</p>
        <button class="bg-blue-500 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4">Buy</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you its working. However, the border line is not touched to the top and bottom of the card.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. Indeed, the line does not touch the top/bottom of the card because of the `padding`classes applied (`px-4 py-10 sm:p-20`). Delete these classes and the line will touch top/bottom. Add these classes to the child element (where `grid` classes is applied) to keep the padding with line touching top/bottom!